A question about formula of confidence interval

I dont understand the sentence "likewise, there's a 95% probability that the interval ... will contain μ". Could somebody explain the logic to me? How does it suddenly jump to the conclusion that it will contain μ?  Thanks.

"As will be shown later" is not a "sudden jump!"  What does the later demonstration do for you?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I cannot see a need to edit the question. What part is unclear?

I can understand the difficulty you have with that poorly-constructed description. The problem is the start of the earlier sentence ("Now, if a specific sample mean is selected, say, $\bar{X}$"). This makes $\bar{X}$ sound like a specific sample mean such as, for example, 5.2. The problem is that the rest of the sentence, and the following sentence beginning with the word "Likewise", are only correct if $\bar{X}$ denotes the random variable not a specific realization.
If your query is about why does the probability statement about covering $\bar{X}$ equal the probability statement about covering $\mu$, the answer is straightforward. First, let's assume $\bar{X}$ denotes the random variable. Now
$P(\mu - 1.96.SE < \bar{X} < \mu + 1.96.SE) =  P(\bar{X} - 1.96.SE < \mu < \bar{X} + 1.96.SE)$ because the second probability's double inequality can be deduced from the first probability's double inequality by rearranging the terms in the first probability's double inequality.
The opening description (shaded green) is also confusing by using the words "interval estimate" for both a specific sample interval estimate and for the (random) interval estimator.
